# Why is my insertion sort not getting the first element?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

My insertion sort sorts every number but the first number. It sorts from the second element to the last element, but it never includes the first element. What is wrong with my insertion sort. I based this code off the pseudocode of the book CLRS and I cannot debug what is wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
void InsertSort(int data[], int length)
{
    //std::cout<<length<<std::endl;
    for(int j = 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        int key = data[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while(i > 0 && data[i] > key)
        {
            data[i + 1] = data[i];
            i--;
        }
        data[i+1] = key;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        std::cout<<data[x]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    int foo [] = { 18, 2, 77, 0, 12071 , 21, 45, 98, 54, 80};
    InsertSort(foo, 10);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output: 18 0 2 21 45 54 77 80 98 12071

here is the pseudocode i received from the book

```
for j = 2 to A.length
    key - A[j]
    //Insert A[j] into the sorted sequence A[1.. j - 1]
    i = j -1
    while i > 0 and A[i] > key
        A[i+1] = A[i]
        i = i -1
    A[i+1] = key
```

If there are copy right issues, I will take down the pseudocode.

As you can see my first element is not sorted and for some reason is never sorted. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `while(i > 0 ...`

Comment: Should it be while i >= 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the while loop to

```
while(i >= 0 && data[i] > key)
```

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
void InsertSort(int data[], int length)
{
    //std::cout<<length<<std::endl;
    for(int j = 1; j < length; j++)
    {
        int key = data[j];
        int i = j - 1;
        while(i >= 0 && data[i] > key)
        {
            data[i + 1] = data[i];
            i--;
        }
        data[i+1] = key;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        std::cout<<data[x]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // insert code here...
    //std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";

    int foo [] = { 18, 2, 77, 0, 12071 , 21, 45, 98, 54, 80};
    InsertSort(foo, 10);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right. It now works, but is the pseudocode now considered to be wrong? The pseudocode states while(i > 0). I did not type it incorrectly.

Comment: @user1470901: The pseudocode is using sequences indexed from 1.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!